# Setting up more than 4KB of session data

Tags: codeigniter, session

How can i setting up more than 4KB of session data in Codeigniter Framework.

Answer (score 5):

Cookies are limited to 4KB of data.  To get around this you can store your session data in the database.  The documentation on the [Sessions Class](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html) details how to do this.  Check out the section titled *Saving Session Data to a Database*.